# Django forms instead of primary key in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='type')

class Flash(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Lense(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Is it possible in django admin, instead of having `pk` to the type field on the Product form, to have all the forms that model with that `pk` has?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post ContentType model and you probably didn't set uncode for the model

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

If you do as above you will see Product titles instead of `pk`